# How to make a global functions file in PHP?

Tags: php

Been quite a while since I've touched up on PHP, so I'm trying to get my head around creating a global functions file for my project. Been concentrating on Javascript/AngularJS lately.

So far, I have two files. My `globals.php` file, and my `api.php` file.

**globals.php:**

```
class Globals
{
    public function guid()
    {
        return "testing";
    }
}
```

**api.php:**

```
include 'globals.php';
$globals = new Globals();

echo $globals->guid();
```

Obviously, the above is erroring out since I am most probably defining my class incorrectly.

How can I use the `globals.php` files functions in my `api.php` file?

Comment: hey.. the code is working for me... What is the error you are getting while executing api.php

Comment: There's no error in your code. It works fine.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code, assuming you use php tags, observe capitalization, correct paths, etc. This is where actual error messages help.

Comment: After further debugging, `$globals->guid()` returns nothing.

Comment: check http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9100f50302322b8f9328f9a8cabdaad65b37ea05 which show that `$globals->guid()` returns something when the file is correctly included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing you work on a linux box where filenames are case sensitive, you should use

```
include 'Globals.php';
```

except for this remark, the code is working.

Also make sure you have php markers `<?php` at the beginning of both files and `?>` at the end.

test you include path with

```
<?php
if (file_exists('Globals.php')) {
  echo "file exists";
} else {
  echo "file does not exist";
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, probably should have kept everything to the same. All files are in lower case. I will make that edit now.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you store your class files, in this case `Globals`. The `includes_path` value is predefined generally but you may need to set this at runtime to point to where you have the file.

```
set_include_path( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT' ).'/includes';
/* Assuming you store the file in that location */
include 'Globals.php';
```